# Who is regarded as one of the world's leading experts on the German language?

Tags: resource, culture

Professor David Crystal is widely regarded as a leading expert on the English language who published numerous language books. He held and holds numerous public lectures on the English Language.

Here is [a list of David Crystal books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Crystal), a [recent interview with him](https://www.cambridge.org/elt/blog/2019/07/09/interviewing-david-crystal/) and [his website](https://www.davidcrystal.com/GBR/David-Crystal).

One of my favourite books is [The Story of English in 100 Words](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12567848-the-story-of-english-in-100-words).

David Cyrstal is both a professor on the English language and a writer of popular English language books.

- Does German have any current well-known authors on the German language in terms of the scope and breadth as regards the German language?
- What German authors are there that have published well-regarded popular German language books ?

Comment: I think it would help your question if you could describe the type of books and their topics in the question in order to narrow down the scope a bit beyond "books on German language".

Comment: Added a wiki page with a list of David Crystal published books.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this question is on topic since it seems to ask for an opinion. Also, I'm not sure the phrase "German equivalent" is adequately defined. Are there famous German language experts? Yes, the Brothers Grimm are two. But I have no idea if Jacob Grimm meets your idea of a "German equivalent".

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatol_Stefanowitsch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastian_Sick https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_Schneider

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Das soll ein Scherz sein, oder? (bzw. sogar drei Scherze)

Comment: *Stefanowisch is both a professor on the German language and a writer of popular German language books* :)

Answer (score 2):

The German public doesn't care enough about language for professors to write popular books about the subject. Books about the language usually limit themselves to dealing with [prescriptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) questions such as: Are forms such as *diesen Jahres* or *gewunken* acceptable? The most popular German dictionary calls itself *Rechtschreibwörterbuch*, as if the most important thing about a word was its spelling (and not its meaning). If an expert makes a public appearance, the purpose usually is to criticise. In the instance of the [Unwort des Jahres](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unwort_des_Jahres_(Deutschland)), the object of the criticism is either the concept behind a word or the way a word is used for a political purpose.

While looking for an example of an academic writing a book that is at least somewhat accessible to the general public, I was reminded of [R. E. Keller](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_Ernst_Keller). Tellingly, he wrote *[The German language](https://d-nb.info/369150783)* (1978) in English. ([Martin Durrell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Durrell), responsible for the latest editions of the ever-popular *[Hammer's German grammar and usage](https://d-nb.info/1154315355)*, held the same [chair](https://minerva.manchester.ac.uk/germans-in-manchester/exhibits/show/hs-chair-of-cerman) at Manchester as Keller.)

Comment: Every generalization is wrong ;)

Comment: Make a counterexample. It would genuinely brighten my day if there was a popular book about the German language written by a German academic. (I assume OP was talking about the present day, so I wouldn't count people like Jacob Grimm, Hermann Paul or Theodor Frings.)

Comment: @planetmaker If your comment is true, it carries no more informational load than "every penguin is a bird". If your comment is to carry some informational load, what you actually implied was "your generalisation is wrong". For this to have any value to the author of the reply or to the reader, the truth of your assertion needs to be demonstrated with evidence.

Answer (score 2):

One person which comes to my mind might be [Stephan Elspaß](http://www.germanistenverzeichnis.phil.uni-erlangen.de/institutslisten/files/at/03300_at/3390_at.html). One of his main topics is the diversity and regional differences in the languages; a topic on which he published many academic but also a few popular texts.

However this question does not have a definitive answer - comparing the achievement of people, and then even for different fields is intrinsically a subjective task.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there are any German equivalents. It is a cultural difference. In German-speaking countries, popularity is perceived as un-scientific. That is why university professors tend to avoid writing popular books. The most popular books about the German language are written by laypeople like Bastian Sick and fall far behind the quality of David Crystal’s books.

Answer (score -1):

The only one who comes to mind is **[Peter Eisenberg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Eisenberg_(Linguist))**. He wrote the two-volume *Grundriss der deutschen Sprache*, which is the most popular and arguably best linguistic introduction to the German language, the 1998 edition of the *Duden-Grammatik* and much of the *Wahrig*.

However, he is also an old white man and sometimes it shows.

Comment: Findest Du es nicht rassistisch, sexistisch und altersdiskriminierend, seine Äußerungen dem Geschlecht, der Hautfarbe und dem Alter zuzuschreiben? Was schreibt er denn, was ein Schwarzer nicht geschrieben haben könnte? Was, das nicht von einer Frau geschrieben sein könnte? Was, das nicht von einer jungen Person stammen könnte?

Comment: “old white man” is eine feststehende Wendung, die nicht zwingend etwas mit Alter, Aussehen ist Geschlecht zu tun hat, wenn sie hier auch zutreffen. Eisenberg wird mitunter als (zu) konservativ kritisiert.

Comment: Wenn "old white man" nur "eine feststehende Wendung" ist, "die nicht zwingend etwas mit Alter, Aussehen..." zu tun hat, dann gilt dasselbe für "fauler Schwarzer" wohl auch, oder? Entweder sind alters-, rassisch- oder sonstwie bedingte Stereotypen unangebracht oder sie sind es nicht. "Alte weiße Männer" als grundsätzlich "reaktionär" hinzustellen ist auch nichts anderes, als Schwarze als "faul" zu etikettieren. Du scherst da über einen ziemlich grobstolligen Kamm.

Comment: Diese rein rhetorischen Unterstellungen von Rassismus sind ekelhaft. "Alter weißer Mann" bezeichnet offensichtlich eine Haltung. Im Gegensatz zur Hautfarbe ist man für seine Haltung selbst verantwortlich und kann selbstverständlich dafür kritisiert werden. Die Wendung ist nicht rassistisch, sie enthüllt Rassismus: es geht nicht darum, dass die alten weißen Männer schlechter wären als andere, sondern dass es in dieser Welt die längste Zeit ihre Meinungen waren, die als einzige sichtbar waren und Gewicht hatten.

Comment: (Der Vorwurf an Eisenberg konkret wäre für mich der, dass er trotz all seiner Kompetenz sich öffentlich vor allem mit Kritik der geschlechtergerechten Sprache hervortut, die aber nicht über die Platitüde "Genus ist nicht Sexus" hinausgeht.) Aber der *Grundriss* ist ein Klassiker, wenn auch mehr für Studenten als die allgemeine Öffentlichkeit gedacht.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Alter, weißer Mann bezeichnet offensichtlich keine Haltung, sondern identifiziert eine solche mit Alter, Geschlecht und Hautfarbe und das sind Merkmale von Rassismus, Sexismus …, auch wenn es aus einer politischen Richtung kommt, die früher für das Gegenteil stand. Offenbar ist man gar nicht gegen Rassismus oder Sexismus, wenn es die richtigen trifft. Wenn man eine konservative Haltung kritisieren will kann man das ja schreiben, statt nahezulegen, alle weißen, alten Männer seien konservativ und alle jungen, schwarzen Frauen seien es nicht. Das "ekelhaft" geht a.d. Absender zurück.